# circular Rotating wheel in query mobile example?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need a simple example of rotating wheel .I googled it but not find any  link .I am thinking  to make like that

A circle  having four button .on click any buttons which present on display on top.

OR

If I  rotate clockwise or anticlockwise .it rotate only one step.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain yourself more. By 'rotating wheel', do you mean a [Pie Menu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_menu)?

Comment: yes something like that ..please see pic .if I select + it come on top  instead of this ^ pic.When I click star it come top instead of +

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin called [PrettyPieMenu](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~laine9/demo/ppmenu/piedemo.html). Try that.

Comment: But It'now what user want

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590391/circular-wheel-implementation-in-jquery-mobile