# Circular wheel implementation in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Is there any API in jQuery mobile while make this type of circular wheel? By default login is below the down arrow. If I click product&offers it come below the down arrow. If I Click
ATM Locator rotate and display below the down arrow?

[image]

Comment: Definitely not an out of the box solution to what your looking for but maybe you can get jquery knob to do it: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Comment: and of course you would like it to be dragable? do you reload the page after clicking or the page remains the same?

Comment: page is same .But images will change when user click the images